# Dart extensions are available for wrong data type in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have two extensions for differente types `String` and `DateTime`. Could someone please to explain me the next behavour on the pictures?

Why extensions for `String` and `DateTime` are visible in suggestions for `int` type?!

[image: Invalid extension method]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the SDK:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40062

It's been fixed and the fix should be available in the next stable release of Dart/Flutter. It's likely already available in both Dart/Flutter dev versions as it's been a month or so since the fix.

Comment: Sure, but it was worth adding the answer in case others are searching and come across it. It's worth marking this as the correct answer if you believe if it is :-)